# What kind of logic does Python uses to handle Boolean expressions?

Tags: python

So I just started learning Python, and while I was just playing with the shell I came around a weird thing.

```
print(5!=6==True,"=",True) #Gave False=True
print(5!=6==False,"=",True) #Gave False=True
print(5!=6!=True,"=",True) #Gave True=True
```

Can anyone explain to me why does this happen

Comment: See [operator precedence](https://realpython.com/python-operators-expressions/#operator-precedence).

Comment: When in doubt just use parenthesis...

Comment: You have to be careful how you pass these conditions without parentheses. `(5!=6)==True` returns a True while `5!=6==True` returns False.

Comment: @Julien While i agree with the advice, it doesn't answer why. Do you know why? I don't. `5!=(6==True) -> True` `(5!=6)==True -> True` `5!=6==True -> False`

Comment: `5 != True == True` gives True. 6 is never == True, thus the whole statement is False. Does that help answer?

Comment: are you assigning any meaning to the printing of your hardcoded `"=",True`?  Because they dont really do anything, every you are curious about is in the first part of your prints.

Answer (score 4):

the expression `a op1 b op2 c` is equivalent to `(a op1 b) and (b op2 c)`

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/

mainly used to enable easy declaration of constraints such as `min < x < max`

Answer (score 3):

What's interesting about this is it isn't about regular operator precedence.  Adding parentheses doesn't give the same result:

```
>>> 5!=6==True
False
>>> (5!=6)==True
True
>>> 5!=(6==True)
True
```

The first one is actually parsed as a chained comparison:

```
5!=6 and 6==True
```

which is `True and False` (result `False`).

The more natural use of chained comparisons is:

```
x = 5
if 0 < x < 10:  # True
```

which is parsed as:

```
0 < x and x < 10
```